# PayPal button sends amount donated to MySQL server

Tags: mysql, paypal

I need my PayPal donation button to send/report the amount donated to an SQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think **it's best to use the [official paypal documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/#id08A6F0T90BI).** The flow is pretty much the same for payments as for donations, except for a hidden `cmd` field:

```
<!-- for donations use this field-->
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
```

You should set a "return URL", to where the user should be redirected after completing the donation.

```
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="return" value="URLspecificToThisTransaction">
```

The next important thing is **the "notify_url"** which will be called by paypal after the payment has been performed. But you can also configure this on your paypal account.

**The notify URL should point to a page (e.g. php page, java servlet, ...) which needs to perform the validation of the payment.** Your page should call a paypal service, which is described [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/). It's a kind of handshake.

[image]

Paypal offers a [simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSimulator/) to test this.

**Alternatively, if you use PHP** there are some existing libraries that could help you. You could use [this "Paypall payment interaction (2005)"](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2249-PHP-Process-Paypal-payment-interactions.html) class. It contains a readme file with usage instructions, or you can simply follow [this tutorial](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/05/donation-center-php-mysql-paypal-api/). But I'm not sure if this is still valid.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. After making the post I got swamped with other stuff. I have been looking at some of the suggestions you have provided and am vary happy with some of them. I will get back to this topic asap and give you a final answer for my solution. Again, thank you vary much.